# Response not reaching interceptor

Tags: angularjs, request, interceptor

I've spend a few hours on this to no avail, hopefully some1 could shed some light into this. (thanks !)

**My interceptor:**

```js
appRoot.factory('myInterceptor', ["$window", "$q",'$location', function ($window, $q,$location) {
    var sessionRecoverer = {
    responseError: function(response) {
        // Session has expired
        if (response.status == 401) {
            $location.path('/#/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
};
return sessionRecoverer;

  }]);
```

**Application End Request:**

```
        private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            var routeValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
            if (routeValues != null)
            {
                if (routeValues.ContainsKey("action"))
                {
                    var actionName = routeValues["action"].ToString();
                    if (actionName.ToLower() != "login")
                    {
                        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Page Result:**
[image]

Comment: what version of angular you use ? . try change to `$location.path('/login');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I'm using Angular js (1). The issue seemed to be related to some weird settings on my web.config, authentication form timeout forward to default url kinda of thing. Couldn't capture the weird settings so I could post it here, but that kinda solved the issue.